# Difference between rulefit & skope-rules Python Packages

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, algorithms

[RuleFit](https://github.com/christophM/rulefit) is an implementation of a rule-based prediction algorithm based on the [rulefit algorithm from Friedman and Popescu (PDF)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ejhf/ftp/RuleFit.pdf).

[skope-rules](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/skope-rules)
Skope-rules is a Python machine learning module built on top of scikit-learn and distributed under the 3-Clause BSD license.

Both the packages generate rules. Do both the packages rely on [The RuleFit algorithm by Friedman and Popescu (2008)](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/rulefit.html), and implement the same algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Skope rules poster: http://2018.ds3-datascience-polytechnique.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/DS3-309.pdf

They made themselves a differentiation

> However, our approach mainly differs in the way that decision rules are chosen: semantic deduplication based on variables composing each rule as opposed to L1-based feature selection (RuleFit).

In my personal opinion and after seeing the semantic deduplication package, I will be quite careful as it made some strong modifications of logical rules by default.